# Jasper report error while filling table

Tags: jasper-reports

I've problem with *JR* report. When I generate report which contains table component I get error:

> No components bundle registered for namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components

I've not idea what it mean, because when I run report from *iReport* or *ANT* everything is all right I get my PDF report, but when I run it form my web app I get this error.

Anyone can help me?

Below is full stack trace

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No components bundle registered for namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.getBundle(ComponentsEnvironment.java:150)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.getManager(ComponentsEnvironment.java:168)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.(JRFillComponentElement.java:65)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.visitComponentElement(JRFillObjectFactory.java:1598)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseComponentElement.visit(JRBaseComponentElement.java:81)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractObjectFactory.getVisitResult(JRAbstractObjectFactory.java:89)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementGroup.(JRFillElementGroup.java:82)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.(JRFillElementContainer.java:90)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.(JRFillBand.java:90)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.getBand(JRFillObjectFactory.java:498)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.(JRBaseFiller.java:496)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:153)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:55)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)
    at JavaScriptApp.JavaScriptApp.genPDF_DB(JavaScriptApp.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at teamworks.connector.JavaReflectionConnector$1.execute(JavaReflectionConnector.java:81)
    at com.lombardisoftware.server.core.ManagedAssetClassLoaderUtil.executeWithManagedAssetClassLoader(ManagedAssetClassLoaderUtil.java:51)
    at teamworks.connector.JavaReflectionConnector.execute(JavaReflectionConnector.java:49)
    at com.lombardisoftware.component.javaconnector.worker.JavaConnectorWorker.invokeJavaMethod(JavaConnectorWorker.java:149)
    at com.lombardisoftware.component.javaconnector.worker.JavaConnectorWorker.doJob(JavaConnectorWorker.java:82)
    at com.lombardisoftware.component.common.workflow.ExecutionJob.doJob(ExecutionJob.java:409)
    at com.lombardisoftware.server.ejb.workflow.EJBWorkflowManagerBean.doResumeWorkflowEngine(EJBWorkflowManagerBean.java:1111)
    at com.lombardisoftware.server.ejb.workflow.EJBWorkflowManagerBean.resumeProcess(EJBWorkflowManagerBean.java:392)
    at com.lombardisoftware.server.ejb.workflow.EJSRemoteStatefulEJBWorkflowManager_82478d70.resumeProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.lombardisoftware.server.ejb.workflow._EJBWorkflowManagerInterface_Stub.resumeProcess(_EJBWorkflowManagerInterface_Stub.java:518)
    at com.lombardisoftware.component.common.workflow.EJBWorkflowManagerDelegateDefault.resumeProcess(EJBWorkflowManagerDelegateDefault.java:142)
    at com.lombardisoftware.component.common.workflow.EJBWorkflowManagerDelegateWebSphere$6.run(EJBWorkflowManagerDelegateWebSphere.java:84)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
    at com.lombardisoftware.client.delegate.common.WebsphereDelegateHelper.doAsCurrentSubjectContextSensitive(WebsphereDelegateHelper.java:175)
    at com.lombardisoftware.client.delegate.common.WebsphereDelegateHelper.doAsCurrentSubjectContextSensitive(WebsphereDelegateHelper.java:159)
    at com.lombardisoftware.component.common.workflow.EJBWorkflowManagerDelegateWebSphere.resumeProcess(EJBWorkflowManagerDelegateWebSphere.java:82)
    at com.lombardisoftware.component.common.web.WebWorkflowManager.callEJBWorkflowManager(WebWorkflowManager.java:778)
    at com.lombardisoftware.component.common.web.WebWorkflowManager.processRequest(WebWorkflowManager.java:273)
    at com.lombardisoftware.servlet.ControllerServlet.doCommon(ControllerServlet.java:376)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: What version of *JR library* are you using?

Comment: Did you see [Error by filling a report with a htmlcomponent hc:html](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/541478/error-filling-report-htmlcomponent-hchtml) post?

Comment: I'm using JR 5.0.0. With htmcomponent I've the same problem... No components bundle registered for namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent

Comment: IMHO, something wrong with your application classpath or *JR library* has broken settings

Comment: I'm newbee and i really don't know what I should do. My application is IBM BPM 8.0 based on websphere. Can you tell me what should I check?

Comment: Check the *jasperreports_extension.properties* in the *jasperreports-x.jar* file - Is it customized?